# CSS > select first element in tree

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to just select the first blockquote of an email body that looks about like this:

```
<div class="myclass">
    <br><p></p>
    <div><div> <!--sometime less sometime more div-->
        <blockquote> <!--the blockquote I wanna select-->
            <div> <div> <br>
                <blockquote>
                    <etc...>
                </blockquote>
            </div> </div>
        </blockquote>
    </div></div>
</div>
```

the problem is the formating can be different depending on emails and there can be one or several div before the first blockquote,
so using:

```
.myclass > div > div > blockquote {}
```

wont work all the time,
this :

```
.myclass blockquote:first-of-type {}
```

will select every blockquote

So I just want to select the FIRST blockquote whatever its position on the html tree.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? Selects the first nested blockquote of the container `.myclass` but not any `blockquotes` that are children of the first `blockquote`.

```css
.myclass blockquote:not(blockquote blockquote) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass">
  <br>
  <p></p>
  <div>
    <div>
      <!--sometime less sometime more div-->
      <blockquote>
        <!--the blockquote I wanna select-->
        <div>
          <div> <br>
            <blockquote>
            </blockquote>
          </div>
        </div>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```